# Background doesn't render transparent

Tags: transparency

I set film to transparent, RGBA. No objects in background. In preview and until the last moment of rendering it is transparent and then the white background appears in rendered .png.

[image]

[image: White background]
[image: transparency enabled]
[image: nodes]

Answer (score 0):

In the *Compositor* you use an *Alpha Over* node to put the image over the blurred *Env* (=Environment) output of the *Render Layers* node.

[image: environment alpha over]

The environment is the world background, in your case you have an image called "Untitled.001" there which is just plain white.

[image: world background]

It is useless to enable *Film* > *Transparent* if you later bring the background back in with plugging *Env* into the *Alpha Over* node. Also the *Blur* node for a plain white image is kind of nonsense because even if blurred it will still be just a plain white image, so you could as well delete it.

And the *Viewer* node in the *Compositor* will only show something if you enable the *Backdrop* option in the menu bar, otherwise you can delete it, too.